# Datediff of two max datetime values from two tables and update a third table based on the difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update

I have three tables Account, Solditems and Appointments.

I need to update IsOverSixYears column of every Account row, when the date difference is bigger than 6 years in related SoldItems and Appointments tables.

An account can has multiple Solditems and multiple Appointments, so I need to find the latest sold item and the latest appointment and compare them, the IsOverSixYears flag should be set based on the account latest sold item and appointment.

Here is my attempt which is give me bad results:

```
    Update AccountBase
    Set  IsOverSixYears=0
    Update AccountBase 
    Set  IsOverSixYears= Case
     WHEN   ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,(Select Top (1) Si.SellDate order by Si.SellDate desc),(Select 
     Top(1)app.AppointmentDate order by app.AppointmentDate desc)))< 6*365 
      THEN 1
     WHEN   ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,(Select Top (1) Si.SellDate),(Select Top(1)app.AppointmentDate)))>= 6*365 
      THEN 0
     END
    FROM [dbo].[AccountBase] acc inner join [dbo].[SoldItems] Si on acc.accountnumber = Si.accountnumber
 inner join Appointments app on acc.AccountId=app.accountId
```

I think the inner select is problem because this query give me results like the inner query ignored the order by clause:

```
Select Si.SellDate,app.AppointmentDate, 
(Select Top (1) Si.SellDate order by Si.SellDate desc) as Latest 
FROM [dbo].[AccountBase] acc inner join [dbo].[SoldItems] Si on acc.accountnumber = Si.accountnumber
       inner join Appointments app on acc.AccountId=app.accountId
       Where Si.accountnumber='V033072'
```

Result:

```
SellDate                AppointmentDate         Latest
2006-07-06 00:00:00.000 2017-08-17 09:00:00.000 2006-07-06 00:00:00.000
2006-07-06 00:00:00.000 2017-08-17 09:00:00.000 2006-07-06 00:00:00.000
2011-08-08 00:00:00.000 2017-08-17 09:00:00.000 2011-08-08 00:00:00.000
2017-08-17 00:00:00.000 2017-08-17 09:00:00.000 2017-08-17 00:00:00.000
2011-08-08 00:00:00.000 2017-08-17 09:00:00.000 2011-08-08 00:00:00.000
```

It not differs from the Selldate.

I already tried Max function on datetime fields but it give me runtime error:

An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

How can rewrite this query to work properly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably don't need multiple nested subqueries for this. You will need to include sample data to go along with your expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use a `FROM` clause and aggregate *before* joining.  The logic you want looks something like this:

```
update ab
    set IsOverSixYears = (case when AppointmentDate > dateadd(year, 6, max_SellDate) then 1 else 0 end)
    from AccountBase ab left join
         (select si.accountId, max(si.SelltDate) as max_SellDate
          from Solditems si
          group by accountId
         ) si
         on si.accountId = ab.accountId left join
         (select a.accountId, max(a.AppointmentDate) as max_AppointmentDate
          from Appointments a
          group by accountId
         ) a
         on a.accountId = ab.accountId ;
```

Your question doesn't specify what to do if a date is missing.  Nor even what direction the 6 years goes in, but this assumes that `sellDate` is the older date.

Comment: The direction can go both ways in this case.
Also the on a.accountId part cant be bound. Maybe its my mistake.

Comment: It was useful, I changed a few things and working, thank you.